# Change Quick Link FIelds on Account Record

Tags: lightning, account, contact, related-list, custom-view

When I'm in the Account record, I hover over the related Contacts in the "Quick Links" view. Is there a way to change which fields appear when I hover? I'm not finding anything obvious in Object Manager for the Account or Contact objects. I was hoping to add/replace some of the fields with custom fields.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields are coming from the same page layout related list fields configurations. Like go to Edit Page -> Account Layout which is applicable for the current User/RT (you can see the name of the assigned layout on flexi page) -> go to Layout -> click on Related list -> and configure the fields to be displayed under quick links related list here.[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is part of the your Account's page layout configuration. 
You can add the columns in the Contacts Related List section on the account page layout.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to change the related contact layout on accont. That will work for you.